# typedef structure used to define another structure?

Tags: types, initialization, embedded, structure, typedef

I'm a newbie in coding especially in embedded systems. I'd like to ask what does this code mean?

```
typedef struct _Device_cb
{
USBH_Status (*Init) (USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev ,
USBH_DeviceProp_TypeDef *hdev);
void (*DeInit) (USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev , USBH_DeviceProp_TypeDef
*hdev);
USBH_Status (*Requests)(USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev,
USBH_DeviceProp_TypeDef;*hdev);
USBH_Status (*Machine) (USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev ,
USBH_DeviceProp_TypeDef,*hdev);
}
USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef;
```

I know that this is a structure name `USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef` what puzzles me is the code that uses this structure in conjunction with another structure/array. Here's what I mean.

```
USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef USBH_HID_cb =
{
USBH_HID_InterfaceInit,
USBH_HID_InterfaceDeInit,
USBH_HID_ClassRequest,
USBH_HID_Handle
};
```

Is the previous `USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef` structure used to assign types to the entries found in the next structure/array named `USBH_HID_cb`?

Is it just like saying for example u8 USBH_HID_InterfaceInit like assigning a specific type to a variable?

Also, the pointer enclosed with the parenthesis kinda is confusing to me especially because another thing(or variable used in a function) is following it.

Btw, I read this(codes) from a documentation about USB OTG because I want to configure my STM32F4Discovery as a USB host for my USB webcam.

Comment: You need to learn about structure initializers and function pointers.

Comment: ohhh. I just realized something! Thank you and sorry for asking this stupid question. :/

what I find confusing is the function pointers. Well, gotta do some reading about that. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code fragment is not *another structure* but rather a declaration of an *instance* of `USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef` with an initialiser.

`USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef` is a type, while `USBH_HID_cb` is a *variable* of type `USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef`.  The first four members of `USBH_HID_cb` (which happen to be function pointers) are initialised by the functions:

```
USBH_HID_InterfaceInit,
USBH_HID_InterfaceDeInit,
USBH_HID_ClassRequest,
USBH_HID_Handle
```

To see better what is going on, consider the following simpler example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x ;
} tMyStruct ;

tMystruct a = { 0 } ;  // create instance tMystruct with member x = 0 ;
```